# Android Emulator - The emulator process has terminated msg after Fedora upgrade to 38

Tags: android

After upgrading from Fedora 37 to 38, I'm getting The emulator process has terminated msg and can't figure out how to fix it.
i can see there is error libvulkan.so: failed
here is the last few lines:

```
2023-06-02 13:23:14,567 [  96499] SEVERE - Emulator: Sansung S21  API 33 - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
2023-06-02 13:23:14,568 [  96500] SEVERE - Emulator: Sansung S21  API 33 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-06-02 13:23:14,568 [  96500] SEVERE - Emulator: Sansung S21  API 33 - OS: Linux
2023-06-02 13:23:15,576 [  97508]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Sansung_S21_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:23:42,320 [ 124252]   WARN - #c.i.d.PerformanceWatcherImpl - UI was frozen for 15310ms, details saved to /home/blade/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/log/threadDumps-freeze-20230602-132332-AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639-15sec
2023-06-02 13:24:06,554 [ 148486]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.s.e.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/getVmState call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2023-06-02 13:28:38,655 [ 420587]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:28:41,141 [ 423073]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel API 33 - cannot add library /home/blade/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
2023-06-02 13:28:48,869 [ 430801]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:28:48,870 [ 430802]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Sansung_S21_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:30:37,055 [ 538987]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_6_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:30:40,540 [ 542472]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - cannot add library /home/blade/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
2023-06-02 13:30:40,921 [ 542853]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - *** Basic token auth will be deprecated soon, please migrate to using -grpc-use-jwt ***
2023-06-02 13:30:41,059 [ 542991] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - adb protocol fault (couldn't read status length)
2023-06-02 13:30:41,059 [ 542991] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
2023-06-02 13:30:41,059 [ 542991] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-06-02 13:30:41,059 [ 542991] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - OS: Linux
2023-06-02 13:31:48,860 [ 610792]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.s.e.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamScreenshot call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2023-06-02 13:31:48,861 [ 610793]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.s.e.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamNotification call failed - UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
2023-06-02 13:31:48,894 [ 610826] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code 139
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:222)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor322.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:206)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:281)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:185)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:98)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-06-02 13:31:48,895 [ 610827] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
2023-06-02 13:31:48,895 [ 610827] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-06-02 13:31:48,895 [ 610827] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - OS: Linux
2023-06-02 13:31:49,048 [ 610980]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Sansung_S21_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:31:49,048 [ 610980]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:31:49,048 [ 610980]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_6_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-02 13:31:58,317 [ 620249]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - cannot add library /home/blade/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
2023-06-02 13:31:58,496 [ 620428]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - *** Basic token auth will be deprecated soon, please migrate to using -grpc-use-jwt ***
2023-06-02 13:32:34,781 [ 656713]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.s.e.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamNotification call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2023-06-02 13:32:34,781 [ 656713]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.s.e.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamScreenshot call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

Installed from: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/09/18/step-by-step-android-studio-fedora-37-installation/2/

I tried to:

1. remove android studio
   commands I used:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/android-studio
sudo rm -rf /opt/android-studio
sudo rm -rf /home/blade/Android
sudo rm -rf /home/blade/.android
sudo rm -rf /home/blade/.local/share/Google
sudo rm -rf /home/blade/.gradle
sudo rm -rf /home/blade/.cache/Google
sudo rm -rf /home/blade/.config/Google/
```

2. tried selecting software as graphics
3. tried to make new pixel device with x86 instead of x86_64 and tried selecting software as graphics also
4. tried re-install sdk platform & all sdk tools, closed android studio and re-started
5. 1.8TB space available
6. tried different versions of system images Tiramisu 33, R 30
7. tried booting LTS kernel vs latest

can't think of anything else to try, looking for suggestions
How to fix this libvulkan.so: failed error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, fixed it.

I added the file "advancedFeatures.ini" in .android/advancedFeatures.ini to get it all working, works now in graphics hardware.

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```